# How to play Minecraft offline?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just lost my broadband, and am left only with mobile devices with any online access. My main PC is offline - and it seems the newest Minecraft launcher doesn't believe one can have no network access. As I start it, I'm asked to log in or register or choose my existing account.. It seems all three options fail without network access, and I can't pick anything else (there's no UI other than the login).

I can get any software to that PC using a pendrive, or edit whatever locally but I have no way to get it online currently. How can get Minecraft to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MCPatcher launcher has the capability to launch Minecraft, supposedly to be used to test whether your set of mods work with each other. In the 'Game' tab of the launcher, press "Test Minecraft" to run it in offline mode. Note that you will not have the same inventory as before, your username will be "Player", and you will have the default skin. You can only join offline mode servers that don't already have someone named "Player" logged in.

[You can download the latest version of MCPatcher from the Minecraft Forums thread.](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1496369-162-161-152-147update-710-mcpatcher-hd-fix-410-04/).

Comment: Considering I'm playing offline I really don't care about joining whatever servers. Playing Single Player doesn't seem affected.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:** After some testing by the asker, it seems this is not how MineCraft works any more with the new launcher.*

If I understand things correctly, you have to have logged in with the specified user name *at least once* while online in order to play in "offline mode" with it.

You will also need to be online at least once in order to download the actual game (the launcher does not contain any game binaries, just the code needed to verify your login and start up the game).

If you copy the `.minecraft` folder from a computer which you have logged into MineCraft before, you *might* be able to just copy over the config files to the "offline" computer.

Comment: I don't think copying over files would work. The new launcher appears to use session tokens, and I expect playing offline would require that a valid session token had been generated at least once on that computer.

Comment: But is the session token bound to some unique identifier on the person's computer? I'm thinking it should work so long as the token is copied over along with the binaries (and I'm assuming it is stored along with the configs in the `.minecraft` folder).

Comment: Yes, that's the nature of session tokens. It's possible that Minecraft's session tokens *aren't* tied to the computer and account, but it's unlikely since that eliminates much of the point of having session tokens. Someone would have to actually try it to confirm.

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion doesn't work. I played Minecraft on that computer many times in the past, and it automatically suggests the login which I had used before. It's the first time I've gone offline since 1.6 - the old launcher probably behaved the way you suggested, the new one simply doesn't seem to be aware I'm offline; it tries (and fails) to authenticate my old login when I click "Play" and doesn't suggest "Play offline" at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having a similar issue, where I am trying to play Minecraft on a network where Mojang's servers are blocked by the firewall. In the past, I've been able to play offline in these situations, but when I tried using the latest version at the time (1.8.3), it kept trying to download files, and would fail because they were blocked or my wireless card was disabled, and it would fail to start.

I tried making a new profile and using an older version of Minecraft that had once been fully downloaded on my machine on an unblocked network (1.8.1). I forced the profile to use this version of Minecraft, and I successfully was able to open my Minecraft client without downloading any other software, such as MCPatcher (which I also cannot download because the MCForums are blocked here).

It seems the Minecraft client requires whatever version you are using to have ALL files for that version downloaded locally to the machine. Whenever I tried opening 1.8.3, it kept trying to download files related to Minecraft Realms, which I don't even need for playing offline, or so I would think.

For future reference purposes, my client output can be found [here](http://paste.md-5.net/qodaralawu.vhdl) for the failed attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what phone you have, you can tether or share Internet with your computer and it will use your phones Internet.just google how to do it on your device. I wouldn't really use this unless you have unlimited or at least 750mb-1gb of Internet though, your Internet might not be capped.

Comment: Especially if the system or installed software decides to download a few gigabytes of updates right then....

Answer (score -1):

As long as you have a valid account and have used it once before, Magic Launcher (magiclauncher.com) has a Play Offline option which allows you to use your username when you play offline.