# Can you install and play minecraft on an offline PC?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I see some information that says your PC must be online the first time you install/register your mojang account.

Is there a way to do this, and then move files / installer to a completely offline (airgapped) PC?

Conversely, if I do get my first install done online - can I save specific files, and nuke the machine and reinstall windows, and copy over the files which were online onto a machine which isn't online?

Any other possible solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play Minecraft offline?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124660/how-to-play-minecraft-offline)

Comment: No, that has the 'use once online first' option (although they were still having problems).  I would prefer a 'use never online, just download f/an online source; sneakernet to airgapped computer'.  If necessary, would do it online, then reformat OS, and put 'approved' files onto a clean install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## yes, you can move the Minecraft Launcher files to an offline computer,

and it will start fine, remembering your installed versions, their icons and names, and so on,

## but, you'll need to be online anyway to boot up the game

because the launcher needs to;

1. log in to verify you've bought the game,
2. re-download any version files to verify itself, i assume, seeing when i attempted it failed to boot because it couldn't connect to the `launcher.mojang.com` domain to get a proper `1.16.json` (even though i had it in the proper location on disk).

### for those curious how i did this;

1. i set up a virtual machine and did a clean install of Windows 10 on it, making sure it itself was up-to-date with proper drivers, VirtualBox Guest Additions, and so on (this allows for host-to-guest file transfer),
2. i copied the `%programfiles(x86)%\Minecraft Launcher` and `%appdata%\.minecraft` files to the guest OS's proper locations,
3. i disconnected the guest OS from any network,
4. i started up Minecraft Launcher manually--it won't pop up in the Start menu like it will in a usual install.

Comment: So, it seems I must expose a windows machine to the internet in order to play minecraft.