How do I open the Minecraft Launcher offline? (Windows 11) (2024)
I don't have access to the internet, and so the Minecraft Launcher gets stuck on the login screen. I know Minecraft Java has an offline mode, but I can't reach it since there is no UI other than the Xbox login screen. I also can't download the old launcher (no internet.)
"Offline Permissions" in the Microsoft Store does not change this.
Does anyone know how I can get to the "Play Offline" option?

Here is the link to your answer: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124660/how-to-play-minecraft-offline?rq=1

@pppery the linked question is from 11 years ago, and is out of date. The launcher has changed significantly since then, requiring a Microsoft account instead of a Mojang account (which has been completely phased out).

I cut my internet and it still works (I can play offline without an issue)... And I'm using the Microsoft Store version of the launcher. I could also replicate it with the standalone version. Can you make a screenshot?

You can't if you've never logged in to the launcher before (which requires an internet connection). This is to prevent essentially pirating the game by requiring a valid account session before you can launch the game offline.
As with most modern paid games, internet connection is required at least once to verify that you do indeed own it.

That's the problem. I have signed in when I have internet available. That's how I tried turning on "Offline Permissions." It still doesn't work.
Is there any way I could perhaps create a shortcut that directly launches Minecraft?
